# java jndi - how to find some bean in weblogic

Tags: java, weblogic, jndi

I have weblogic with two managed servers, when I open MS1, there is JNDI view and I can see there my session bean. There is MyBean#com node, which can be expanded by package until I locate the last part. When I open it, there is Binding Name: MyBean#com.company.MyInterface.

The bean is annotated with remote annotation sitting inside ear MyApp. Then I have a plain java client. I open InitialContext to the server:

```
ht.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
ht.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://hostname:7081");
ht.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "weblogic");
ht.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "weblogic");
_ctx = new InitialContext(ht);
```

and look it up:

```
_ctx.lookup("MyBean#com.company.MyInterface")
```

but it fails:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'MyBean#com.company.MyInterface' didn't find subcontext 'MyBean#com'. Resolved '']; remaining name 'MyBean#com.company.MyInterface'
```

Can you please help me construct correct JNDI name? I am confused since I can see it in JNDI view in WebLogic 10.3.4. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Ok, I had wrong port in JNDI context. I fixed it and it works fine